# Handle NSView.MouseEntered without creating a subclass of NSView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.mac

In the following theoretical scenario, how would I trigger a function when `NSView.MouseEntered` is triggered without creating a subclass of `NSView`?

```
NSView container;
NSTrackingArea trackingarea = new NSTrackingArea(container.Frame, NSTrackingAreaOptions.MouseEnteredAndExited, container, null);
container.AddTrackingArea(trackingarea);
```

Comment: When, you say creating a subclass of `NSView` what exactly do you mean?

Comment: `public class NSViewSubClass : NSView { }`. I'm receiving an NSView object which I can't replace by my own custom one with added tracking, which is how this is usually done afaik.